# How can I handle error with fetch for 204 No content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I have a fetch request as below;

```
fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'include'
}).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(`Something wrong`);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(`catch block error`);
});
```

My 204 response looks as

```
body: null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
```

My question is how do I handle this since my 204 response is kind of successful, but only thing is the ok flag is false
So it goes and prints "Something wrong" which is not correct for 204 response.

Comment: Why you talk about status code 204 and then there's written `status: 0`?

Comment: It shows 204 No Content in Chrome Dev Tools

Answer (score 3):

You said `mode: 'no-cors'` so you can't look at the response. `no-cors` mode is only useful if:

- you need to send a request
- the request doesn't need any features which would make it preflighted
- you don't need to know anything about the response

You can't read the status (this is why it is reported as `0` in the response you quoted), so you can't tell if it was `204 No Content` or `200 OK` or `500 Internal Server Error`, etc.

You can't read the body, so you can't tell if there was no content by testing it.

---

You need to:

- Remove `mode: 'no-cors'`
- Make sure the server grants all the permissions you need using CORS
- Read the `status` property of the response object to determine if it is a `204` or not

Comment: Actually, the no-cors is a requirement of the called endpoint...Also a cookie is returned in the response....So considering that, not sure if I have any other alternative to handle?

Comment: @copenndthagen — If you need to know what the response is, then `no-cors` can't be a requirement of the endpoint. Possibly the documentation for the endpoint is wrong. Possibly the API developers think you shouldn't care if you get a no content response or something else. Possibly the endpoint is not designed to be used directly from a browser.